# Literature about graph isomorphism and incidence matrix

Tags: graph-theory, computational-complexity

I would like to read some paper, if any, for some classes of graphs, regarding inverting (right/left inverting) the incidence matrix to solve the graph isomorphism problem. Or anyway some known facts related on that problem and derived through the incidence matrix.
Thank you.

Comment: do you mean adjacency matrix? the incidence matrix is vertex-edge matrix, not even rectangular, in general.

Comment: I mean the incidence matrix, it is not square but can have a right or left inverse. If the incidence matrix is $A$, and $I$ the identity, there may exist $R$ and/or $L$ such that $AR=I$ or $LA=I$.